# Not performing calculation on blank field in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df) with the following structure:

```
      date     a       b       c         d         e        f       g   
23/02/2009                                  577.9102        
24/02/2009                                  579.1345        
25/02/2009                                  583.2158        
26/02/2009                                  629.7425        
27/02/2009                                  553.8306        
02/03/2009  6.15    5.31    5.80    223716  790.8724            5.7916
03/03/2009  6.16    6.2     6.26    818424  770.6165            6.0161
04/03/2009  6.6     6.485   6.57    636544  858.5754    1.4331  6.4149
05/03/2009  6.1     5.98    6.06    810584  816.5025    1.7475  6.242
06/03/2009  5.845   5.95    6.00    331079  796.7618    1.7144  6.0427
09/03/2009  5.4     5.2     5.28    504271  744.0833    1.6449  5.4076
10/03/2009  5.93    5.59    5.595   906742  814.2862    1.4128  5.8434
```

where columns a and g have data i would like to multiple them together using the following:

```
df["h"] = df["a"]*df["g"]
```

however as you can see from the timeseries above there is not always data with which to perform the calculation and I am being returned the following error:

> KeyError: 'g'

Is there a way to check if the data exists before performing the calculation?  I am trying to use :

```
df["h"] = np.where((df.a == blank)|(df.g == blank),"",df.a*df.g)
```

I would like to have returned:

```
      date        a       b       c         d           e       f       g       h
23/02/2009                                       577.9102       
24/02/2009                                       579.1345       
25/02/2009                                       583.2158       
26/02/2009                                       629.7425       
27/02/2009                                       553.8306       
02/03/2009     6.15     5.31    5.8     223716   790.8724           5.7916  1.0618
03/03/2009     6.16      6.2    6.26    818424   770.6165           6.0161  1.0239
04/03/2009      6.6    6.485    6.57    636544   858.5754   1.4331  6.4149  1.0288 
05/03/2009      6.1     5.98    6.06    810584   816.5025   1.7475  6.242   0.9772
06/03/2009    5.845     5.95    6.00    331079  796.7618    1.7144  6.0427  0.9672
09/03/2009      5.4      5.2    5.28    504271  744.0833    1.6449  5.4076  0.9985
10/03/2009     5.93     5.59    5.595   906742  814.2862    1.4128  5.8434  1.0148
```

but am unsure of the syntax for a blank data field. What should that be?

Comment: `KeyError` usually means there is no column named `g` in your data frame. You may check your `df.columns` firstly.

Comment: Can you post code to initialize the dataframe please?

Comment: Can you add to the question the output of  "df.columns"